# How can we get readers feedback after completing viewing and reading a certain document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

How can we get readers feedback after completing viewing and reading a certain document in SharePoint document library.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Sreeni

Answer (score 0):

If they open the document using a specific link, you could specify the "source" to redirect the user to a survey page when the document is closed.  This would be easy to craft and place on a page or email out to user.

If they open the document directly from within a library or search you would need jquery or similar to alter the link used to open the doc though.